# Special setup for a linux server to route to itself

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing, iproute2

I've got two linux servers in question. When one server initiates a request for a specific IP address that the other server has, I would like the initiating server to route the request back to itself on one of its own IP addresses.

How might this be done? Iptables? Iproute2? I'm a newbie to both and am somewhat confused by all their options. If either one can do it, I'd love to see examples of each so I can learn a little extra!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't described the usecase for that, and i don't know the limitations, i can only suggest adding the target IP to one of your interfaces on the initiating server. If supported in the kernel, you can use dummy interface (`dummy0`) for that.

```
modprobe dummy
ip addr add 1.2.3.4/32 dev dummy0
```

Comment: Beautiful! I had no idea it would be that easy! To enable *two* dummy interfaces I had to use the command `modprobe dummy numdummies=2`, and to make that persistent, the line `option dummy numdummies=2` needed to be added to `/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf` (debian/ubuntu). Works perfectly!